# Using a model object in React (without Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a text editor app in React. My basic structure is

#### model

```js
class TextLine {
  text: string
  folded: boolean
  indentLevel: number
  index: number
  model: TextEntryModel
  fold: () => this.model.foldLineAtIndex(this.index)
}

class TextModel {
  lines: TextLine[]

  setText: (text: string) => void // splits the text, creates TextLine objects and sets each line's model to this (line.model = this)

  foldLineAtIndex = (index: number) => {
    // we're actually folding all the "children" of this line.
    const startingLine = this.getLineAtIndex(index);
    let previousIndentLevel = startingLine.indentLevel;
    // start with the next line
    for (let i = index + 1; i < this.lines.length; i++) {
      const thisLine = this.lines[i];
      if (thisLine.indentLevel > previousIndentLevel) {
        thisLine.folded = true;
      } else {
        return; // if we've reached a line with the same indent level, we're done.
      }
    }
  };
}
```

#### basic component structure

```js
<App> // state = { model: new TextEntryModel() };
  { model.lines.map(line => 
    <Line 
      line={line} 
      onClick={line.fold}
    />
  )}
</App>
```

Something like that, that's a big reduction. When you click the `Line`'s accessory (not in my sketch) it calls `fold` on the `line`.

Clicking the line does indeed change the lines in the model, I can confirm this. But the lines don't rerender with their new `folded` value. At first I just had `model` as an instance property of the `App` class, and I thought maybe moving it to the `App`'s state would help, but no dice.

I guess React's question of "have the props changed?" is not affirmative when a property of a property of the state has changed. (I would hope that when `model` changed it would pass `Line` a new `line` prop but maybe `model` isn't being registered as changing).

So, I could do this with Redux, possibly with a reducer whose type is just `{ model: TextModel }` and use selectors to drill down in each `Line`, or possibly with a reducer with the simple type `TextLine[]` (or `{lines: TextLine[]}`).

But I like the idea of using a real model-ass model. I think this is how I'd do it, correctly, in say Swift or Angular, but it doesn't seem to fit the React paradigm as far as I can tell, which seems weird. So I imagine I'm missing something.

How do I go about this?

Comment: How are you updating the state? If you just modify state in-place, w/o calling `setState`, nothing will happen--React relies on `setState` to know if the state has changed. It doesn't deep-watch anything inside the state, which is why all the warnings about not modifying state directly.

Comment: It did occur to me that I wasn't calling any setState. So do I need to be basically re-setting state immutably, almost as if it were redux? Where `App` passes some function all the way down to `Line` and that function is something like `model.line[index].fold(); setState({model})`?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly. Nutshell: yes (maybe). Unrelated: unless it's some sort of passion project, I sure wouldn't tackle a text editor--they're *very* hard to do well.

Comment: Well, the HTML textarea takes care of a lot of the input stuff for me... we'll see! :) Trying to basically clone and update FoldingText.

Comment: Not really--IIRC FoldingText has embedded formatting; not possible under a `<textarea>` tag. Once you get into embedded formatting a "line" becomes a completely different animal. If it's just plain text I'd honestly poke around to see what's already out there, although I'm sure it's a fun project.

Comment: I've poked, believe me. But yes, the level of typing and formatting being in the same place is a large next step. Very, very large indeed...

Comment: You'll be *significantly* better off picking a WYSIWYG editor and working within its framework. It's much, *much* easier to add folding to something that already supports a notion of blocks than to build a WYSIWYG editor. People do theses on this (ropes, gap buffers, piece tables, oh my).

Comment: Yes, I was looking at Draftjs after seeing your last comment. Any other suggestions on where to look? I think I’m going to build on the folding concept with static text, just as a project, and then move into what is clearly the much deeper world of an actual editor. Tried wading into the VSCode source, but drowned pretty quick!

Comment: There's no simple non-plain-text text editor :)